# PowerShell: Array of Arrays

Tags: powershell, shell-script, array

I have files with the following structure:

```
c:\root\dir1\001 (BRP-01 Some) Text.tif
c:\root\dir2\002 (BRP-01 Some Different) Text.tif
c:\root\dir3\001 (BRP-01 Some) Text.tif
...
```

Ultimately, I want to pull out files based on a contiguous range of the first three digits of a file name. My initial approach is to try an `Array of Arrays` to store directory information and file information ... which will then be subsequently acted upon to extract and evaluate the first three numbers and further manipulate. However, my experience with arrays in PS limited and I am having problems when it comes to storing data, accessing that data, or both.

If you could help correct my syntax, it would be appreciated. Also, if there is a better approach I might consider, I am open to alternate approaches.

```
PS C:\root\> Get-ChildItem *.tif -recurse | foreach-object {$a=$_.DirectoryName; $b=$_.Name; $c+=@(@($a,$b)); foreach ($i in $c) {echo $i[0]}
# I realize something "breaks" after $c+= ... but I am unsure what. The script runs but I cannot access the respective fields as expected or the data isn't being populated as expected.
```

I would expect the array to return something like the following once I have the correct syntax:

```
$i[0]: 
       c:\root\dir1\
       c:\root\dir2\
       c:\root\dir3\
$i[1]: 
       001 (BRP-01 Some) Text.tif
       002 (BRP-01 Some Different) Text.tif
       001 (BRP-01 Some) Text.tif
$i[0][1]: c:\root\dir1\
```

I am rather confident that I can manipulate the data once I can firmly grasp how the `Array of Arrays` is build and data is called from it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating this a lot. you don't need any further "data formatting" after you ran your `Get-ChildItem` command. You simply need to `Group-Object` your output depending on the first 3 chars of the filenames like this:

```
$AllItemsGrouped = Get-ChildItem *.tif -recurse | Group-Object { $_.Name.Substring(0,3) }
```

This will return your objects, grouped into their respective prefixes, without any information getting lost:

```
PS C:\Install\testdir500> gci | group-object { $_.Name.substring(0,3) }

Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
    3 001                       {001test - Kopie (2).txt, 001test - Kopie.txt, 001test.txt}
    2 002                       {002test - Kopie.txt, 002test.txt}
    1 003                       {003test - Kopie - Kopie.txt}
```

for example, if you expand a group, the content looks like this:

```
PS C:\Install\testdir500> gci | group-object { $_.Name.substring(0,3) } | select -expand Group -first 1


    Verzeichnis: C:\Install\testdir500


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       30.11.2020     09:55              0 001test - Kopie (2).txt
-a----       30.11.2020     09:55              0 001test - Kopie.txt
-a----       30.11.2020     09:55              0 001test.txt
```

You can then access it in different ways, for example like this:

```
foreach ($Group in $AllItemsGrouped) {

    $CurrentGroup = $Group.Group
    Do-Something -With $CurrentGroup

}
```

Comment: Thank you. `Group-Object` is a skill I didn't have in my toolbox. I appreciate the guidance.

Comment: @Brian you're welcome. it's one of my favorite cmdlets. good thing for the toolbox